# What does "[ERROR] file doesn't exist" means when doing maven install?

Tags: java, maven

When I execute maven install in my gitlab build, I get the following error message:

> 12338 [INFO] Installing com.mycompany:myartifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT at end
>   12338 [INFO]  12338 [INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:3.3.0:install
>   (default-install) @ myartifact --- 12411 [ERROR] file doesn't exist:
>   file:/root/.m2/repository/com/mycompany/myartifact/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/myartifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

I don't understand what does it mean. The file obviously doesn't exist because it was never installed in that environment, so it's strange that maven would complain about it.

I suppose this error hides some other error, like no write rights? But I see not other error in log. The build seems to be successful.

Comment: Are you running the command as root?

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens as it is the default for docker, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a clean install, maybe it's just a local repository issue

```
mvn clean install
```

Comment: The simplest solution, run maven without any extra parameters. Those was some extra parametres that caused the error. Still, I'd like to know how to interpret such error when it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

When you do maven install, It usually looks into your .m2 folder and searches for the existence of the dependencies(mentioned in pom.xml). If it doesn't exist, maven will automatically download it. So the build will be successful.

Comment: But it's not the dependency, it's the artifact himself+